# SQL to turn rows into column in snowflake

Tags: sql, count, pivot, aggregate-functions, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

[image: Input Data]I have one table in snowflake like below:

[image: Expecting Output]

Could someone help me out on this.

Comment: Google for "SQL pivot query"

Answer (score 2):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select account_id,
    sum(case when topic = 'COLLEGE_SPORTS_OTHER' then page_view else 0 end) as cnt_college,
    sum(case when topic = 'ENTERTAINMENT'        then page_view else 0 end) as cnt_entertainment,
    sum(case when topic = 'LOCAL'                then page_view else 0 end) as cnt_local
from mytable
group by account_id
```

Answer (score 2):

pretty straight forward using pivot():

```
select
*
from
yourtable
pivot(sum(page_view) for "Topic" in ('COLLEGE_SPORTS_OTHER', 'ENTERTAINMENT', 'LOCAL') )
as p
```

snowflake documentation: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/pivot.html